# How to keep stereo output after echo cancellation with pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, headset

I have an issue with my headset where my microphone plays the audio that I hear from my PC (application audio such as spotify/youtube etc. gets picked up by my mic)

To fix this I have implemented an echo cancellation script that runs the following commands on system startup:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
pactl unload-module module-echo-cancel
pactl load-module module-echo-cancel aec_method=webrtc source_name=echocancel sink_name=echocancel1
pacmd set-default-source echocancel
pacmd set-default-sink echocancel1
```

This has fixed the above mentioned issue.

Unfortunately this has changed the output of my headphones from stereo to mono and I was wondering if there is a way for me to change it back from mono to stereo or if there is something extra that I can add to the script to prevent this from happening in the first place.

I have tried the following command as an attempt to fix it does not revert back to stereo:

```
pacmd load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=echocancel-stereo master=echocancel1 channels=2 channel_map=left,right
```

I am fairly new to Linux (I recently switched from Windows) so I guess you could call me a noob and I definitely know very little about how audio works.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: did you got the soultions?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution was to specify master sink and source devices and include the `use_master_format` option. I created the following bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# masters
source_master=alsa_input.usb-Audio-Technica_AT2005USB-00.analog-stereo
sink_master=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic.HiFi__hw_sofhdadsp__sink

# names
source_name=input.echo-cancel
sink_name=output.echo-cancel

# properties
source_properties=device.description=$source_name
sink_properties=device.description=$sink_name

# other options
use_master_format=yes

# load the module
pactl load-module module-echo-cancel \
  source_name=$source_name \
  source_master=$source_master \
  source_properties=$source_properties \
  sink_name=$sink_name sink_master=$sink_master \
  sink_properties=$sink_properties \
  use_master_format=$use_master_format
```

You will need to change the `source_master` and `sink_master` to match the devices on your system. You can use `pactl list sinks` and `pactl list sources` to get the names.

There may be other ways around this, but this was my solution.

Reference: [PulseAudio Docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#module-echo-cancel)